# Prove that the function $f: \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$ defined by $f(m,n) = (2m+3n,3m+2n)$ is not onto

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm a student and I came across this problem, first I had to prove that this function is injective, which I did. But I really struggle to prove that this function is not onto. I'll appreciate the help!

Comment: A harder way to prove this is to evaluate the determinant of $\begin{pmatrix}2&3\\3&2\end{pmatrix}$ (which is not $\pm 1$).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** $(2m+3n)+(3m+2n)=5(m+n)$, which is always a multiple of $5$.

Comment: +1. You were faster!

Comment: I still can't understand how to use your hint:/

Comment: If $(a,b)\in\mathbb Z^2$ is such that $5\nmid a+b$, then $(a,b)$ cannot belong to the range of $f$.

Comment: thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

Can you find integers $m,n$ such as $2m+3n=0, 3m+2n=1$ ??